# Is it possible to add web-to-lead data to the thank you page URL?

Tags: javascript, web2lead, website-integration

I would like to use the web-to-lead form data on the thank you page. Is it possible to append the data to the retURL? Since it uses POST method I don't know what to do...
Thanks in advance for your help!